# How to show dots for whitespaces in Emacs 24.5?

Tags: emacs, emacs24

I wonder, isn't there a simple way to show dots for whitespaces in Emacs 24.5? I've tried to find information and and have always found some complex solutions which worked for some people and didn't for others. Isn't there a de-facto and easy way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `whitespace-mode`, or even `global-whitespace-mode` to see them in all buffers. If you only want to see spaces, configure it with the following:

```
(setq whitespace-style '(space-mark))
(setq whitespace-display-mappings '((space-mark 32 [183] [46])))
```

Or, if you want a different colour for the dots, include also

```
(setq whitespace-space 'your-favourite-whitespace-face) ; <- insert the face
(setq whitespace-style '(face spaces space-mark))
```

You can **customize** the settings rather then set the values manually.

Comment: `if you only want to see spaces, ` -- what else can I see?

Comment: @OskarK.: Tabs, newlines, spaces before tabs, tabs before spaces, etc. Check the documentation of whitespace-mode.

Comment: I would suggest using `M-x customize-option RET whitespace-style RET` rather than clobbering the defaults with setq like that.

Comment: @phils: True, that's what I do here. But I used this approach for testing the exact setting.

Comment: can I make the dots smaller?

Comment: @OskarK.: You can select any character you like. Try experimenting with the values.

Comment: can I make the dots smaller?

Comment: If you are using a graphical version of emacs you could customize the whitespace-* faces and make them smaller, if you really wanted to.